# Resize windows line by line, not pixel by pixel

Tags: window, gui-emacs

Is it possible enforce that Emacs changes the window size line by line, not by some count of pixels, to eliminate the situation when I see a half-line on the screen?

I mean window in Emacs sense (commands like `C-x }`, `C-x ^` do it). Funny, but frame resizing does it in line-by-line manner. I use the macOS Cocoa version.

(Currently I can just drag separator by mouse and put it in-the-middle of the line height).

Comment: So, it should be relevant to `mouse-drag-mode-line` and `mouse-drag-vertical-line`.

Comment: And both calling `mouse-drag-line`. So what needed is to force `mouse-drag-line` do enlarging step by step.

Comment: Like `enlarge-window` it does.